# Wordpress regenerates thumbnails on each load

Tags: wordpress, function

When I'm working in localhost, every uploaded image in wordpress generates thumbnails and after that I can edit manually these thumbnails and replace .jpg files with the edited ones. But when I placed my site online, every time I load the home page, it generates all the thumbnails AGAIN and that erases my edited thumbnails. I also assume that makes my site slower.
Is there a way to disable that?

Comment: Weird.  I've never heard of WordPress doing that.  Have you tried disabling your plugins and/or changing to one of the standard themes to see if a plugin or your theme is causing it?  Can't see why it'd behave differently on localhost though.

Comment: I'll try disabling stuff. I'll let you know how it worked